# Is etherscan/bscscan limited to the last 100K transactions?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, bscscan

I was exploring a contract transaction and I was not able to see the contract creation as last transaction, but I found that there are all limited to the last 100K transactions.

I know that I can export the earliest 5000 records starting "from" a given date until another "to" date, clicking in Download CSV Export link.

Is there any other way to explore all the transactions?